# Do cables need to be secured in a framed cavity?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I’m installing two new ceiling fans below an existing ceiling that cannot be disturbed because it’s decorative, so I’m framing a new drop ceiling cavity consisting of 2x4s to run 14/3 cable and set the two fan junction boxes with steel brackets.

Can I run the cable loosely in this space, connecting only at the boxes, or does this wiring have to be secured somehow?  I'm in Kansas and NEC applies.

Comment: you might want 12/3

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want to simply *remove* a decorative ceiling, if you're willing to cover it up anyway.

Comment: It's not being covered, @Huesmann. It's being _partially_ covered by a wiring duct.

Comment: Why can't you staple to your new framing? The question isn't clear.

Comment: Have you considered surface-mount channel (like Wiremold) for the wiring? Might be less intrusive.

Comment: The question is clear as mud. If it's about running through an existing space, it's a duplicate. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/15694/18078 It's unclear how much that is the case from the question, since it refers to "framing a **new** drop ceiling cavity"

Comment: This could _definitely_ use an [edit] to clarify. Maybe the addition of a picture or drawing showing us exactly what's going on here would help. In any event, if you're putting up _new_ framing of any sort, and the wiring will be in this new framing, the most likely interpretation is that the cable should be secured to said framing. If it's not being inspected, you could probably _get away with_ not securing it, but why quibble over a few wire staples for under $1 total cost?

Answer (score 3):

If you can get to the areas, and not running cable through a cavity,  the wire needs to be anchored.  Since you said you are framing in a new ceiling you need to follow the code for new construction.
Staple the wire 8 inches from the box minimum. and every 4 1/2 feet.

Your choice of cable should be rated for the breaker that services it. #14 for a 15 amp breaker,  #12 for a 20 amp breaker.  The reference from another member to 12/3 cable is good advice. The 12/3 will give wire to power the fan and a light separately. A good idea even if the new fan does not have a light, the wire is there for the future.  The 12/3 can be used with a 15 or 20 amp breaker.

Comment: The cable _is_ running through a cavity, and there's not a new ceiling. I suggest a re-read.

Comment: @isherwood No, you’re misunderstanding. The OP is constructing a new channel on the surface of their ceiling. This channel will be accessible during construction so the wire that will run inside it must be secured. The exception to securing requirements is for wiring being fished inside entirely pre-existing spaces, not new spaces.

Comment: Yep. Not a new ceiling.

Comment: It seems to me that the cable is running through some framing that is (to be) newly built and open. Therefore, the cable should be attached to the new framing. If one were to attach the cable (even if it weren't _required_), one would be exceeding the _minimum_ required by code and that is allowed; ergo, no harm, no foul.

Comment: What if the OP builds the chase and *then* runs the wire through it? :-p