# Running NM wire romex along rafters in vaulted ceilings

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

So my ceilings look like this:  /\

I want to replace / relocate my breaker panel.

The circuits run along the rafters into the attic space (small, cant stand up).

My questions:

- Can I just fish romex along the rafters?
- If I do that, it doesn't seem possible to staple them every 4' - so how do you secure romex in non accessible places where you are fishing wire?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. If you're fishing cable, you don't have to secure it.

> ## National Electrical Code
>
> **334.30 Securing and Supporting.**
>
> **(B) Unsupported Cables.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>
> (1) Is ﬁshed between access points through concealed spaces in ﬁnished buildings or structures and supporting is impracticable

Comment: Thanks so much.  Where do you find the NEC online?

Comment: @Vigrond I didn't. I copied the text from [my other answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/11636/33), which I copied from my code book.

Comment: @Vigrond -- see [this link](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/code/safety.html) for all the Code that you'll ever need